# My string is not going into its if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, token

So I pass in a string called SUB. I compare it using strcmp to "SUB." However, it's not going into my if loop. I'm not sure what's wrong. Here is some of my code:

```
char* single;
int singleLen= strlen(inputString);
char singleTemp[singleLen+1];

strcpy(singleTemp, inputString);   //to tokenize without modifying input string
single = strtok(singleTemp, " \r\n");
if (strcmp("SUB", single) == 0){
    if (size_list(stack) < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough elements in stack.\n");
        exit(-2);
    }
    x = peek(stack);
    stack = pop(stack);
    y = peek(stack);
    stack = pop(stack);
    stack = push(stack, x-y);
    //increment PC
    PC++;       
    return stack;
}
```

Could the problem be in my input script? I think I have everything correct there - there's no extra whitespace after SUB or anything. Just in case, here is my code up to the error where it cannot go into SUB if loop.

```
CONST R0 4 ;A=4
CONST R1 0 ;B=0
CONST R2 0 ;Constant 0 comparison
CONST R4 1
PUSH R2
PUSH R0
SUB        ;ERROR OCCURS HERE
POP R3
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: OH! I found the error with MUL. It was because of a formatting error in my script itself. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Nitpick: `if` does not start anything called a "loop". A loop is something that iterates, `if` doesn't do that. Also, you should simply add `printf("single is '%s'\n", single);` before the `if`.

Comment: `strtok(singleTemp, " \r\n");` maybe?

Comment: I assume there is no `\r` either (just to be sure, you should output `strlen(single)`), and `singleTemp` is a sufficiently long buffer to house a copy of `inputString` ? (Edit: whoops, two ninjas said the same thing)

Comment: Sorry, I do `printf("single is %s\n", single)` before the if. It prints out 'Single is SUB', like it's supposed to be. When I posted my code up, I removed my printf statements for better readability...I guess I should put them back in?

Comment: Just to be safe, make your printf `"single is '%s'\n"`, that way you see if there's some hiding whitespace.  My guess would be that your input has a tab after it that `strtok` isn't catching.

Comment: How is `singleTemp` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've added doesn't make any sense, since the entire flow isn't visible.

```
char* single;
int singleLen= strlen(inputString);
char singleTemp[singleLen+1];
```

presumably there's a missing `malloc()` that initializes `single`, and then some missing I/O that reads in the data so that the `strlen()` call acts on actual data? Also, no need to use variable-length arrays here in my opinion (*or* dynamic allocation), just make them both static and e.g. 512 characters long or so.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that - I omitted that code because I thought it might take too long. The way it works is that I have an array of input strings and I malloc for each string in the entire array. Then I pass each input string of the array into the function I posted here.